# How do I use the find method of a datatable with a compound key?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am working on a windows form application. How do i use the find method of a datatable to find a row if the datatable has a compound key?

Table Structure
Col A, Col B, Col C

Col A and Col B make up the compound key.
I want to find the row where the value in Col A is 6 and Col B is 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an overload that you can use to pass in two different values to the find method.  [Here is the MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6dh4x2h(VS.80).aspx).

So you would most likely be doing something like.

```
DataTable.Rows.Find(6,5)
```

Comment: Is it me or am I reading that doc wrong? It says the return value is an array of DataRow objects, which it isn't.

Comment: Yes, text in MSDN is a typo... return value is a single DataRow object

Answer (score 13):

When you "set" the Primary key of the datatable, the parameter value is an array of DataColumns...

if your datatable is in variable dt...,

```
dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {dt.Columns["ColA"], dt.Columns["ColB"]};
```

Then pass an array of object values to the Find() method

```
object[] keyVals = new object[] {6, 5};
DataRow dr = dt.Rows.Find(keyVals);
```

or, just

```
DataRow dr = dt.Rows.Find(new object[] {6, 5});
```